# How assign shortcut to custom function?

Tags: python, shortcut

i have this simple function in the Blender text editor :

```
import bpy
bpy.ops.object.select_pattern(pattern="Cube?")
bpy.ops.object.select_pattern(pattern="Sphere?")
```

I just simply want to run this function using a shortcut. How can i bind a shortcut to it ?

Thanks.

Comment: What's the goal? Just running both operators using one shortcut? Or do you actually want to being able to select certain objects by their name like "Cube" and "Sphere"? Related: [Create keyboard shortcut for an operator using python?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/196483/create-keyboard-shortcut-for-an-operator-using-python/196518#196518)

Comment: This [Run text block](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/195659/73532) addon might help you.

Comment: What is the intention of the script?  If you wish to select all objects with name starting with "Cube" or "Sphere", but not "Cube" and "Sphere" consider using `pattern="Cube?*"` and using `extend=True` to extend the selection.

Comment: I asked that too [(3 hours ago)](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/201367/how-assign-shortcut-to-custom-function#comment338156_201367) and got no answer still @batFINGER

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would have to implement a custom [Operator](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Operator.html) and add your code to its execute method:

```
class OBJECT_OT_CustomOp(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Tooltip"""
    bl_idname = "object.simple_operator"
    bl_label = "Simple Object Operator"

    def execute(self, context):
        
        # Your code here ...
        bpy.ops.object.select_pattern(pattern="Cube?")
        bpy.ops.object.select_pattern(pattern="Sphere?")
        
        return {'FINISHED'}
```

---

**`shortcut.py`** based on [Create keyboard shortcut for an operator using python?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/196483/31447)

```
import bpy

bl_info = {
    "name": "Your Addon Name",
    "author": "Author Name",
    "version": (0, 1),
    "blender" : (2, 80, 0),
    "location": "",
    "warning": "",
    "wiki_url": "",
    "tracker_url": "",
    "category": ""
}


class OBJECT_OT_CustomOp(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Tooltip"""
    bl_idname = "object.simple_operator"
    bl_label = "Simple Object Operator"

    def execute(self, context):
        
        # Your code here ...
        bpy.ops.object.select_pattern(pattern="Cube?")
        bpy.ops.object.select_pattern(pattern="Sphere?")
        
        return {'FINISHED'}


addon_keymaps = []

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(OBJECT_OT_CustomOp)
    
    # Add the hotkey
    wm = bpy.context.window_manager
    kc = wm.keyconfigs.addon
    if kc:
        km = wm.keyconfigs.addon.keymaps.new(name='3D View', space_type='VIEW_3D')
        kmi = km.keymap_items.new(OBJECT_OT_CustomOp.bl_idname, type='W', value='PRESS', ctrl=True)
        addon_keymaps.append((km, kmi))


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(OBJECT_OT_CustomOp)
    
    # Remove the hotkey
    for km, kmi in addon_keymaps:
        km.keymap_items.remove(kmi)
    addon_keymaps.clear()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Comment: About that shortcut link above: Do i have to add keymap/shortcut inside these python codes ? How about adding keymap in preference and attach the command there ?

Comment: You can do both. Either assign it directly (Ctrl+W in the example) and change it later on in the keymap @andio Does that answer your question?

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying to find out how to install this code to Blender to make  it loaded everytime i open Blender.

Comment: great it works.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using >v2.8, this should work.
Very basic and there might be a better way, (almost certainly!!) but it works.
After you run this, a new menu item should show up in your "Select" menu. Right click this item and assign a shortcut as normal.

## Read the comments for a **very** basic explanation of what the various parts do

```
    bl_info = { ## stuff so Blender can find your code
    "name": "My Addon",
    "author": "Your Name",
    "version": (0, 1),
    "blender": (2, 90, 0),
    "location": "View3D > Select",
    "description": "Your addon descriptioin",
    "warning": "",
    "wiki_url": "",
    "category": "3D View",
    }

import bpy
from bpy.types import Operator

class MYADDON_OT_My_Class(Operator): ## stuff to be able to make a menu item
    bl_idname = "object.my_class"
    bl_label = "Test"
    bl_description = "My Description"
    bl_space_type = "VIEW_3D"
    bl_region_type = 'UI'
        
    def invoke(self, context, event):
        ## the main event, this will be ran when your button is pressed
        bpy.ops.object.select_pattern(pattern="Cube?")
        bpy.ops.object.select_pattern(pattern="Sphere?")
        
        return {'FINISHED'}


def menu_func(self, context): ## creating the menu item
    self.layout.operator(MYADDON_OT_My_Class.bl_idname, icon='MESH_CUBE')
    
def register(): ## register the functions so Blender can use them
    bpy.utils.register_class(MYADDON_OT_My_Class)
    bpy.types.VIEW3D_MT_select_object.append(menu_func)
    
def unregister(): ## unregister when the addon is removed later
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(MYADDON_OT_My_Class)
    bpy.types.VIEW3D_MT_select_object.remove(menu_func)
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Comment: Thanks, the custom menu works fine but  I have problem with the script : when tried to remove the menu by running the 'unregistered' function, i got error : RuntimeError: unregister_class(...):, missing bl_rna attribute from 'RNAMeta' instance (may not be registered) . Also, when i press the shortcut, it won't run the command. I check in keymap, the shortcust exists and the command is : object.my_class . But why shortcut doesn't do anything.

Comment: The unregister_class bit is really for when you save this as a file and add it in as a proper addon via the preferences page. If you're running it from the scripting tab simply closing Blender will remove it. The register/unregister stuff is just there because, well, I always put it there and install my addons :)
As for the shortcut not working, it should, it works for me. Perhaps you are choosing a shortcut that is already in use and is causing a conflict. What shortcut did you use? I used CTRL-ALT-W

Comment: Hi i tried to install as add-on. Save your script as .py and install via preferences. But it  doesn't show up in the 'select' menu ? not like when i run it from text editor. What is wrong ?

Comment: Also , when i install as add-on : there's no error , but got warning : upgrade to 2.8x is required. In fact , i'm using 2.83.7 . Any clue ? Thanks

Comment: The `bl_info` requires a `"blender"` member with value at least `(2, 80, 0)` to remove the warning.  https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.AddonPreferences.html

Comment: Ok, I've updated the script to work as an addon, it just needed the correct stuff in the bl_info