# How can I create a mouse Shortcut in Blender 2.8x or 2.9x to select object siblings in a collection with double click

Tags: objects, collections, object-mode, select

I hope you are doing OK.

I want to create a shortcut entry to be able to select a collection with double click in the 3d Viewport but I cant find the right command to put in the identifier.

If I check the console, the command that runs with select siblings is:

```
bpy.ops.object.select_grouped(type='SIBLINGS')
```

But if I go to preferences - Keymaps - 3DView - Object Mode. and create a new entry with that command and Mouse and Double click, it does nothing.

Has anyone tried to do something similar?

Any Advice would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I manage to do it with this config in the keymap configuration:

under preferences - keymap - 3D View - Object Mode (Global)

[image: Keymap Configuration]

Then when working, when doing double click on an object I select the "Collection type" in the sub menu.

Later it remembers the last option used.

Now I can select objects in a collection quickly. Kinda like the "grouping" objects in another software.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to setup a custom operator and probably run it as an add-on.

Explained more in-depth in the link listed below.

## Link

https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/201403/123064